# Integrating Amazon SNS with ServiceStack

Tags: c#, json, servicestack, webhooks, amazon-sns

I'm developing a suite of ETL-style apps which will link cloud-based systems with on-premise systems using [Amazon SNS](http://aws.amazon.com/sns/) and [Amzazon SQS](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) along with some restful services. SNS allows you to set-up an HTTP endpoint as a subscriber and your apps can publish messages to SNS which will be dispatched to your HTTP endpoint (as a json message), as well as an SQS queue, email, sms etc.

What I would like to do is handle the HTTP response from my on-premise app which already incorporates some parts of the servicestack framework. However most of the documentation for servicestack and other restful frameworks describes their usage in a typical request/response pattern. But in this case i'm only waiting for a response from SNS. Can I still use any servicestack code for handling response only messages?

Comment: ok this didn't get very far. After some more research I believe what I need to handle is a webhook or callback. I've spent quite a bit of time googling but it doesn't seem to be a popular topic..at least not in the .NET world. Applications such as SES/SNS and Mailgun amongst others use webhooks to call back your application to inform you of their status. Any way to handle these callbacks from a servicestack application?

Comment: Webhook is just a fancy name, don't get confused by that. Handle the request like any other POST request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon SNS pushes the notifications to your app using a regular POST request, you can handle it like any other incoming POST request.

The endpoint is just a regular url in your app that will receive the POST requests in [JSON format](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/json-formats.html).

Webhook is just a fancy name, don't get confused by that.